# Multithreading Sudoku Puzzle in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sudoku

I made a program that checks a finished 9x9 Sudoku puzzle to see if it is correct.  My program works fine, however, I want to learn how to use threads.  I want a single thread to check every row, a single thread to check every column, and then a single thread to check each block.  Three threads in total.  I'm having trouble converting my code to do this correctly without getting errors.  My code is below:

```
public class Sudoku {

public final Runnable row;
public final Runnable col;
public final Runnable block;
public final Runnable testboard;

public Sudoku(){
    row = new Runnable(){
      public void run(){
           Sudoku.this.testRows(board);
        }
    };
    col = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            Sudoku.this.testCols(board);
        }
    };
    block = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            Sudoku.this.testRegions(board);
        }
    };
    testboard = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            Sudoku.this.testBoard(board);
        }
    };
}

public boolean testBoard(int[][] board) {
    if (!testSize(board)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!testRows(board)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!testCols(board)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!testRegions(board)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

boolean testSize(int[][] board) {
    if (board.length != 9) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if (board[i].length != 9) {
            return false;
        } else;
    }
    return true;
}

boolean checkDigits(int[] array) {
    if (array.length != 9) {
        return false;
    }
    int[] counts = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i
            < array.length; i++) {

        if (array[i] < 1 || array[i] > 9) {
            return false;
        }
        if (counts[array[i]] > 0) {
            return false;
        }
        counts[array[i]]++;
    }
    return true;
}

boolean testRows(int[][] board) {
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if (!checkDigits(board[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

boolean testCols(int[][] board) {
    int[] tmp = new int[board.length];
    for (int col = 0; col < board.length; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            tmp[row]
                    = board[row][col];
        }
        if (!checkDigits(tmp)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

boolean testRegions(int[][] board) {
    for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row += 3) {
        for (int col = 0; col
                < board.length; col += 3) {
            if (!testRegion(board, row, col)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

boolean testRegion(int[][] board, int startRow, int startCol) {
    int[] tmp = new int[board.length];
    int index = 0;
    for (int row = startRow; row < startRow + 3; row++) {
        for (int col = startCol; col < startCol + 3; col++) {
            tmp[index]
                    = board[row][col];
            index++;
        }
    }
    return checkDigits(tmp);
}
}

public class TestPuzzle {

public static void testpuzzle() throws FileNotFoundException{
    Sudoku sudoku = new Sudoku();
    String fileName = "SudokuRight.txt";//This is for the print statment
    Scanner inputStream = null;
    String[] line;
    System.out.println("The file " + fileName + " contains the following sudoku puzzle:\n");
    inputStream = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Sudoku\\SudokuRight.txt"));
    int[][] puzzle = new int[9][9];
    int row = 0;
    while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
        line = inputStream.nextLine().split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            puzzle[row][i] = Integer.parseInt(line[i]);
        }
        row++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(puzzle[i]));
    }

    boolean result = sudoku.testBoard(puzzle);
    System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    if (result == true) {
        System.out.println("This sudoku solution IS valid!");
    } else if (result == false) {
        System.out.println("This sudoku solution IS NOT valid!");
    }
}
}
```

Here is my main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Sudoku x = new Sudoku();
    new Thread(x.row).start();
    new Thread(x.col).start();
    new Thread(x.block).start();
    new Thread(x.testboard).start();
}
```

Here is my file that I scan in:

```
8,3,5,4,1,6,9,2,7
2,9,6,8,5,7,4,3,1
4,1,7,2,9,3,6,5,8
5,6,9,1,3,4,7,8,2
1,2,3,6,7,8,5,4,9
7,4,8,5,2,9,1,6,3
6,5,2,7,8,1,3,9,4
9,8,1,3,4,5,2,7,6
3,7,4,9,6,2,8,1,5
```

Here is my output before I tried using Threads:

```
The file SudokuRight.txt contains the following sudoku puzzle:  

[8, 3, 5, 4, 1, 6, 9, 2, 7]
[2, 9, 6, 8, 5, 7, 4, 3, 1]
[4, 1, 7, 2, 9, 3, 6, 5, 8]
[5, 6, 9, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 9]
[7, 4, 8, 5, 2, 9, 1, 6, 3]
[6, 5, 2, 7, 8, 1, 3, 9, 4]
[9, 8, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 7, 6]
[3, 7, 4, 9, 6, 2, 8, 1, 5]
Result: true
This sudoku solution IS valid!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I want my output to be the exact same as above, but I want to find a way to break my methods down into threads so that the rows, columns, and blocks all get checked concurrently.  Any help would be very much so appreciated.

Comment: Why do you include commented out code?

Comment: The code that is commented out is the code I tried to use to create threads but it does not work.

Comment: 'it does not work' is not a very good problem description. And it's quite confusing that you post code that actually works. You should probably delete all that working code and only show the code that doesn't work, and why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

First create a Callable for each test you are making

```
   Callable<Boolean> testCollumnsTask = new Callable<>(){

           @Override
           public Boolean call(){
              return Boolean.valueOf(testCols(board));
           }
    }
```

Which is alot easier with lambdas

```
  Callable<Boolean> callable = () -> Boolean.valueOf(testCols(board));
```

Do the same for the rest , replace testCols with other tests.

Now the multithreaded testBoard  *(assuming you are using java 8)*

```
public boolean testBoard(int[][] board) {
    List<Callable<Boolean>> tests = new ArrayList<>();
    tests.add(() -> Boolean.valueOf(testCols(board));
    tests.add(() -> Boolean.valueOf(testRegions(board));
    tests.add(() -> Boolean.valueOf(testRows(board));
    tests.add(() -> Boolean.valueOf(testSize(board));

    /*Maybe store this threadPool in a field so you dont create it everytime*/
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    List<Future<Boolean>> results = threadPool.invokeAll(tests);

    for(Future<Boolean> future: results){
       if(!Boolean.TRUE.equals(future.get()){
          return false;
       }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**future.get()** throws a checked exception which you should decide how to handle it.

Comment: What class do I put the callable code in? I'm assuming the Sudoku class constructor? And where do I put the lambdas statement? Do I also replace my current testBoard method with the one you provided?

Comment: In the Callable< > you specify type of the result. Since the result of a test is boolean it makes sense to make the task return boolean. You can replace with the one I provided or change Runnable row to Callable<Boolean> row. Then the lambda is `row = () -> testRows(board) ;`

Comment: This is my first time using lambdas.  So I don't have to use the first block of code you provided with the override? I can just type 1 line of code for each test I want to do (size, row, column, region).  But where do I put the lambda statement.  NetBeans says it shouldn't be in the constructor.

Comment: I replaced my testBoard method with the one you provided and it works, however I didn't put the lambdas statements anywhere.  But it still worked.  The only thing is my code never completes its execution.  Even after it prints the result, it says it's still running until I manually terminate it.

Comment: Yeah you should shutdown the threadPool once you have finished with it. One suggestion about that is to make  Sudoku(threadPool) constructor store the threadPool in field and in your main you create the threadPool, you create a Sudoku , then after your finished `threadPool.shutdown();` `threadPool.awaitTermination(1,TimeUnit.MINUTES);`